# How to plot labels for some cites on the map? using cartopy

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dictionary, cartopy

I have an excel file with the information of some cites, now I want to plot those cites with their name on the map. I wrote the following codes, however, I can't get the name of the cites properly. For each cite I get a label with the whole list of 'name'.Any suggestion is welcome.
[image]

#I could not install PyGMT or basemap or even geopandas,so I just have cartopy.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt       
import cartopy.crs as ccrs               
import cartopy.feature as cfeature 

df = pd.read_excel('./seismogram.xlsx')
lon = df['longitude'].to_list()
lat = df['latitude '].to_list()
name = (df['code']).to_list()

def main():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
    plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 18
    
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([128, 133, 30, 35], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_title("Japan")

    ax.coastlines(resolution='10m') 
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
    ax.stock_img() 
 
    return fig, ax

fig, ax = main()
ax.scatter(lon, lat, color="r", marker="o", s = 15)

zip_object = zip(lon, lat, name)
for (lg, lt, ne) in zip_object:
    ax.text(lg - .05, lt + .05, 
            name, 
            va='center', 
            ha='right', transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), fontweight='bold')
    
        
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please show the plot you obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your for-loop, I'm 99% certain you should be using `ne` in place of `name`:

```
zip_object = zip(lon, lat, name)
for (lg, lt, ne) in zip_object:
    ax.text(lg - .05, lt + .05, 
            ne, 
            va='center', 
            ha='right', transform=ccrs.Geodetic(), fontweight='bold')
```

Easy mistake to make :)

Comment: I am sorry to take your time, you are 100% right